# Using intents inside Service

Tags: android

Can I use an intent inside a service? What should I put in "??????"? I need to call an pedingintent for an alarm inside the service.-

example.

```
public class CalcularHorasService extends Service
{
    public int horaR;
    public int minR;
    private PendingIntent pdIntAutomatico;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId )
    {
        // This line is key
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        Log.v( "SERVICIO", "Entro al servicio" );

        getCalcularHoraSalida();

        setAlarma();

        // Return
        return super.onStartCommand( intent, flags, startId );
    }

    /**
     * Set alarm
     */
    private void setAlarma()
    {
        Intent intSincroAuto = new Intent( ????, AlarmaActivarBroadAuto.class );
        pdIntAutomatico = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( ????, 0, intSincroAuto, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `Intent` require context as first params, so you can put `this` because you want to create Intent inside of `Service` class. `Service` class such as `ContextThemeWrapper` (which is extended by `Activity`) extends `ContextWrapper` which extends `Context`.

so your code can looks like:

```
 Intent intSincroAuto = new Intent( this, AlarmaActivarBroadAuto.class );
 pdIntAutomatico = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, intSincroAuto, 0);
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help you.